# Bluetooth Controller or GamePad not recognized in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, bluetooth, upstart, gamepad

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, a generic bluetooth controller (iPega) used to be recognized as a controller/gamepad right after pairing. Like a USB controller does. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OKkT.png).

Same thing in Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

Could it be for upstart to systemd?

Please help me fix this issue. Thank you all very much in advance.